# How to add svg to div when doing conditional rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg.js

I have a code that is only rendered after some data is fetched from server and variables are set. When using svg.js, it uses SVG.AddTo("#someID"), but the div containing the ID has not been rendered yet because of the conditional rendering. How do I delay the SVG.AddTo, to after the div has been rendered and the id exist? Here is the code (Some things have been removed, for example server fetching):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

import {
    CCol,
    CRow,
} from "@coreui/react";

import * as SVG from '@svgdotjs/svg.js'






const website = () => {

    var draw = SVG().addTo('#svgHere').size('100%', '100%')
    var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' })

    return (
      (typeof dataFromServer !== "undefined") &&

        <CCol>
            <CRow>
                <div id="svgHere">

                </div>
            </CRow>
        </CCol>

    );



};
export default website;
```

I also tried, as by the documentation of svg.js adding this:

```
SVG.on(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var draw = SVG().addTo('#test').size('100%', '100%')
    var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' })
})
```

But then the SVG is never rendered. I later want to create a new svg every time the value of a state changes. How can I remove the current draw? I know about useEffects dependencies but I do not know how I can remove the current SVG and replace it with another one?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make an  component and put your logic there and then in Website component return

```
 return (
  (typeof dataFromServer !== "undefined") &&

    <CCol>
        <CRow>
            <Svg/>
        </CRow>
    </CCol>

);
```

Later when you want a different svg based on your state changes pass whatever you need as props to